# Angular Application hosted on Firebase not importing css files

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-hosting

Pretty self-explanatory.  I'm trying to import css files into my angular app (stuff like material icons and google fonts).  I've added the import statements to the styles.css (global styles file).

For some reason when it is hosted on firebase the css files are not being imported.  I'm completely stumped at this point.  My code is below:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&display=swap);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito&display=swap);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coming+Soon&display=swap);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chilanka&display=swap);

i {
  color: #2b2b26;
  margin-right: 1vw;
  margin-left: 1vw;
}

i:hover {
  color: #f58a18;
}

.icon-container {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Let me know if you want to see any other files.  Also, it displays correctly when served.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build upon @saidutt 's answer, to import those CDN's you should link them in the **head** section of your index.html file.

Like so:

```
<head>
  <!-- your other metadata... -->

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coming+Soon&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chilanka&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
```

An alternative would be to download those CSS files to your project folder and include them in your stylesheets array of your angular.json file:

```
  "styles": [
          "src/googleapis1.css",
          "src/googleapis2.css",
          "src/googleapis3.css",
          "src/googleapis4.css"
        ],
```

... but personally I think CDN's are fine.

Comment: Thanks a million.  I added them to the head section and it all works awesome now!

Comment: You're welcome!  Please select my answer if you found it helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

So, you are preferring to use CDN's.
Look into your networks tab in the browser if the files are even being recorded and loaded.
If not 
try these:
import them into your `index.html` file.

or

include them under the styles array in `angular.json` file